# Prestashop display/hide carrier based on cart rule

Tags: php, module, prestashop-1.6, carrier, cart-rules

I'm using Prestashop 1.6.1.18. I want to set up a cart rule to offer a carrier for purchases over 14 products with the same kind of attribute (grams of pigment: 2 grams). I want to display or hide this carrier on the cart page based on this cart rule.

I have created a cart rule, but I cannot do someting like this on the Actions tab.

How do I resolve this? Is there a module for this? or else, how should I modify the code, just to hide/display the carrier based on the cart rule?

Answer (score 0):

Why hide a carrier, even if you offer it based on a cart rule,  your customer must chose a carrier to be delivred.

Comment: Yes, but this carrier will be optional and the others will be always there